# How to dynamically select rows in a CSV file for conversion?

Tags: javascript, csv, d3.js

Hi I'm trying to parse a csv file using d3.csv, and the csv file is in this format:

```
word, stamp, year1data, year2data, year3data, ..., year60data
program,  a,       1.2,       2.4,       1.3, ...,        5.0
code,     b,       1.4,       5.6,       1.2, ...,        3.4
...
```

So each row is quite long and should be parsed to numbers, which means that for every number there should be a step like this:

```
d.year1data = +d.year1data
```

My question is: is there a good way of handling data like this (instead of manually typing in year1data ... all the way to year60data)? I've found this blog: [Wide and long data](http://jonathansoma.com/tutorials/d3/wide-vs-long-data/) and it seems a workaround; apart from changing the original table format, are there any other methods to make this process easier?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### The 'columns' property

In D3 v4.x there is a new feature that comes in handy: when you load a data file using `d3.csv` (as well as `d3.tsv` and `d3.dsv`) an array property called `columns` is created.

According to the [API](https://github.com/d3/d3-dsv#dsv_parse):

> The returned array also exposes a columns property containing the column names in input order (in contrast to Object.keys, whose iteration order is arbitrary).

Let's see how we can use it.

First, have a look at the following demo (I'm using a `<pre>` element here because I cannot use a real csv file in the Stack snippet). As you can see in the console (with the first object of the data array), all those numbers are actually strings:

```js
var data = d3.csvParse(d3.select("#csv").text());

console.log(data[0])
```

```css
pre{
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<pre id="csv">word,stamp,year1data,year2data,year3data,year4data
foo,a,2,4,6,3
bar,b,8,4,6,2
baz,c,3,7,8,5</pre>
```

However, we can use `data.columns`, which in our case is...

```
["word", "stamp", "year1data", "year2data", "year3data", "year4data"]
```

... to iterate over all columns in the data array.

In the following snippet, we use the `columns` array to coerce the value of all columns that are not "word" or "stamp", since these columns should have strings. This is the function:

```
data.forEach(function(d) {
    data.columns.forEach(function(e) {
        if (e != "word" && e != "stamp") {
            console.log(e)
            d[e] = +d[e]
        }
    })
});
```

And here is the demo:

```js
var data = d3.csvParse(d3.select("#csv").text());

data.forEach(function(d){
 data.columns.forEach(function(e){
   if(e != "word" && e != "stamp"){
     d[e] = +d[e]
    }
  })
});

console.log(data[0])
```

```css
pre{
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<pre id="csv">word,stamp,year1data,year2data,year3data,year4data
foo,a,2,4,6,3
bar,b,8,4,6,2
baz,c,3,7,8,5</pre>
```

In conclusion, you don't need to manually specify all the columns, specially in your case, where you have 60 or more columns. Just use `data.columns`.